# Перебрать все элементы коллекции

Tags: javascript, vbscript, wmi, windows-xp, wsh

Есть такой код на VBScript

```
Set WMIService = GetObject("winmgmts:\\localhost\root\cimv2")
Set WbemObjectSet = WMIService.ExecQuery("SELECT SID FROM Win32_Account Where SIDType=1", "WQL", 32)
For Each WbemObject in WbemObjectSet
  WScript.Echo(WbemObject.Name)
Next
```

Как его перенести на JScript?

Проблема с циклом `For Each`.

Если я пишу так

```
var WMIService = GetObject("winmgmts:\\\\localhost\\root\\cimv2")
var WbemObjectSet = WMIService.ExecQuery('SELECT SID FROM Win32_Account Where SIDType=1', 'WQL', 32);
for (var WbemObject in WbemObjectSet) {
  WScript.Echo(WbemObject.SID);
}
```

цикл не выполняется.

MSDN [говорит](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/wmisdk/swbemobjectset), что у объекта WbemObjectSet есть свойство `Count` и методы `Item`, `ItemIndex`. Однако при обращении к ним я получаю ошибки

```
WScript.Echo(WbemObjectSet.Count);  // Неопознанная ошибка
WScript.Echo(WbemObjectSet.ItemIndex(0).SID);  // Invalid operation
```

Объект `WbemObjectSet` поддерживает интерфейс `IEnumVariant` с методом `Next`. Однако второй и третий параметр этого метода передаются по ссылке. Можно ли его вызвать из JScript?

---

**Update**

Предложенный в ответе метод работает только начиная с Windows Vista. Тогда как в Windows XP у объекта `SWbemObjectSet` нет метода `ItemIndex()`, а метод `Item()` в качестве аргумента принимает не индекс, а path-строку

Answer (score 1):

Проблема решена. Я в метод `WMIService.ExecQuery` третьим параметром передавал флаг `wbemFlagForwardOnly (32 (0x20))`, что отключало навигацию по коллекции по произвольным индексам.

Если же передать флаг `wbemFlagBidirectional (0 (0x0))` (или не передавать третий параметр вообще), то начинают работать `Count` и `ItemIndex()`

```
var WMIService = GetObject("winmgmts:\\\\localhost\\root\\cimv2");
var WbemObjectSet = WMIService.ExecQuery('SELECT SID FROM Win32_Account Where SIDType=1', 'WQL');
for (var i = 0; i < WbemObjectSet.Count; i++) {
  WScript.Echo(WbemObjectSet.ItemIndex(i).SID);
}
```